# Example of a non-measurable set such that inner measure=otuer measure.

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

How can I given an example of a non-measurable set $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ such that $ \mu_{\ast}(A) = \mu^{\ast}(A) $?

Comment: Does this answer your question?:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287913/non-measurable-set-with-infinite-outer-and-inner-measure?rq=1

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much. I used the search option in MathSE at the beginning, but it did not relate to that question. Regards.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you know other examples?